# Rotating logs using RotatingFileHandler by date in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am looking for a method which will allow me to rotate the logs *at midnight* instead of rotating them using the `maxBytes` parameter.

So far, the logs are rotated when a file reaches 10MB.

```
LOG_PATH = os.path.join(APPLICATION_PATH, "log\\My_log.log")

my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH, mode='a', maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=20)
logger.addHandler(my_handler)
```

Is there a way of passing a `date` parameter to `RotatingFileHandler()` so that instead of rotating after the file reaches 10MB it will rotate the file at midnight ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TimedRotatingFileHandler`:

```
my_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH, when='midnight', backupCount=20)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do ^^. By any chance, do you know how can I copy the file to other path after it was rotated ?

Comment: Do you want to change directory or just add suffix to a file name e.g. containing date?

Comment: What I want is: after the file is rotated `at midnight` to move it from the current path to another path